# Check if an object's properties are null in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In Typescript I am checking if an object's properties are null as follows:

```
var addressCountryName = response.address == null 
   ? null 
   : response.address.country == null ? null : response.address.country.name;
```

Both addresses and country can be null ... I also tried:

```
var addressCountryName = response.address?.country?.name;
```

This does not seem to work ...

Is there a shortest way to check for null / undefined?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: The [JavaScript null coalescing operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) is just a proposal for now, so nothing is built into the language.

Comment: There is no safe null-coalescing operator in TypeScript yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned the `null coalescing operator` is still in a proposal stage so you can't access properties using `?.` Your only options currently are to do deep nesting with if statements or ternarys or to consider something like the `get` method from lodash which would let you do:

`let addressCountryName = get(response, 'address.country.name');`

Which will either return the value of name or undefined if any part of the object path was null or undefined.

Here's a CodeSandbox with an example of using lodash:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mm46wkr058

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no [null coalescing operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) in JavaScript.  There are different ways to get around it (like your nested ternary types).  If you're willing to shove helper types and functions into a library somewhere, you could do this:

```
type MyResponse = {
  address?: null | {
    country?: null | {
      name?: null | string
    }
  }
}

let response: MyResponse = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 
  { address: { country: { name: "France" } } } : { address: null }

var addressCountryName = nullSafe(response, r => r.address.country.name); 
// string | undefined | null
```

Where `nullSafe()` is defined like this:

```
interface NullSigil {
  [k: string]: NullSigil;
}

// phantom property to recover T from NullSafe<T>
type OriginalTypeKey = "***originalType***"

type IsNullable<T, Y, N> = null extends T ? Y :
  undefined extends T ? Y : N;

type NullSafe<T, N = NullSigil> = Record<OriginalTypeKey, T> & (
  T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T]-?: NullSafe<T[K], N>
  } : IsNullable<T, NonNullable<T> | N, T>
)

type NullUnsafe<T> =
  T extends Record<OriginalTypeKey, infer U> ? U :
  T extends NullSigil ? null :
  T

function nullSafe<T, U>(
  val: T,
  fn: <N extends NullSigil>(nullSafeVal: NullSafe<T, N>) => U
): NullUnsafe<U>;
function nullSafe(val: any, fn: (nullSafeVal: any) => any): any {

  const nullSigil: NullSigil = new Proxy({} as NullSigil, { get(t, p, r) { return r } });
  const deproxify = Symbol("deproxify");

  function ns<T>(obj: T): NullSafe<T>;
  function ns(obj: any) {
    if ((typeof obj === "undefined") || (obj === null)) return nullSigil;
    if (typeof obj !== "object") return obj;
    return new Proxy(obj, { get(t, p, r) { return (p === deproxify) ? t : (p in t) ? ns(t[p]) : nullSigil } });
  }

  const ret: any = fn(ns(val));

  if (ret === nullSigil) return null;
  if (typeof ret !== "object") return ret;
  return ret[deproxify];
}
```

Yes, it's a mess, that's why I said to shove it into a library.  It works by making a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) that always allows you to drill down into properties even if it is essentially null.

Anyway, it's one option.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

! is the non-null assertion operator in Typescript. ? is for Angular html templates.

Comment: The non-null assertion operator does something entirely different from what OP wants.

Comment: Not sure what you mean ... You mean to use this: response.address!.country!.name? Does not work ...