# Nullcheck Children Chain in Typescript

Tags: typescript, null-check

Using strict null checking is great, but it's also resulting in this sort of silliness:

```
if (x)
  if (x.y)
    if (x.y.z)
      if (x.y.z.stringProperty)
        console.log(x.y.z.stringProperty)
```

Is there a way to do this null checking without repetition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way of dealing with such scenarios is by using an abstraction like `Maybe` (sometimes called `Option`). Example use:

```
import { Option } from 'space-lift';

Option(input)
  .map(input => input.x)
  .map(x => x.y)
  .map(y => y.z)
  .map(z => z.stringProperty)
  .forEach(console.log);
```

As an alternative, one might use something more succinct like [`dlv`](https://github.com/developit/dlv).

```
console.log(dlv(input, ['x.y.z.stringProperty']) as string);
```

Although it might look more appealing due to its compact nature, this solution can never be type-safe. The path expressed as a string cannot be checked against the actual structure of your `input`, hence type assertion.

Comment: A type-safe version of something like `dlv` is totally possible in TypeScript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12290#issuecomment-456670318

Comment: Delve looks like an interesting alternative.

Comment: @CurtisFenner Unfortunately, that's not exactly true. That solution breaks when your object has optional properties (which is the case here). The type of `get(input, 'x', 'y', 'z', 'stringProperty')` is inferred to be `never`.

Comment: There's also [this possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54354538/2887218) which uses a null-safe proxy of the object in question.