# How to make type lookup to original type to defer its return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typing

I built some neat `ts-get` library that helps to live without optional-chaining for some time. But I'm struggling with one typing case that I can't resolve.
Basically, if not a scalar, but an object type is returned from AccessorFunction I want to look up to original `T` type, for an original nested type. For scalars, I want to keep the behavior I have.

Here is the original code:
https://github.com/RIP21/ts-get/blob/master/src/index.ts

Issue is with case like that.

```js
type Original = {
  objectField?: {
    optionalField?: string | undefined
  }
}

const obj = {} as Original

const a = get(obj, it => it.objectField)
//    ^ is of type { optionalField: string } | undefined
// expected type in this case { optionalField?: string | undefined } | undefined
```

If you guys will be able to help it will make our life a bit better and a bit more correctly typed ^_^

Comment: The problem is that the accessor parameter makes everything required. For the first level maybe we could do something like try to lookup property types to figure out what the original type was but this seems like a bad and brittle idea and it would not work for nested objects. Might I suggest not making the parameter `RequiredRecursively` and using `!` instead. This will not be syntactically very bad but it would preserve original types. Something like `get(obj, it => it!.objectField!.nestedObject)`

Comment: I've [tackled this before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54354538/2887218) and the only way I dealt with it was to use phantom types to hold references to the original type