# Check if field inside composition chain is not undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say we have following declarations:

```
interface Inf1 {
  field: boolean | undefined;
}

interface Inf2 {
  field: Inf1 | undefined
}

interface Inf3 {
  field: Inf2 | undefined
}

function fun1(): Inf3 | undefined {
  return {field: {field: {field: true}}};
}
```

I want to check if 3rd nested field in the object returned by `fun1()` equals `true` (or any other value). First try would be:

```
if (value.field.field.field) {
  console.log('This code does not compile because nested `field` objects may be undefined.');
}
```

What will cause compilation error, because `field`s in the middle may be `undefined`.

What I need to do to compile this code is to check if all nested objects are not `undefined`:

```
let value = fun1();
if (
  value &&
  value.field &&
  value.field.field &&
  value.field.field.field
  ) {
    console.log('This code is compiled successfully');
  }
```

Is there a way, to check "on the fly" that those 'fields' which are in the middle are not undefined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if an object's properties are null in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54354340/check-if-an-objects-properties-are-null-in-typescript)

Comment: My answer in that question would work here too, if you like a lot of `Proxy` action at runtime.  e.g., `nullSafe(value, v => v.field.field.field)`

Comment: Wait for [this proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/). In the meantime, use your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you need doesn't exist in JavaScript, so, yes, you have to protect your code with this kind of test:

```
if (value && value.field && value.field.field)
```

With the `strict` (or `strictNullCheck`) option, TypeScript helps you to think to each potential undefined value, but it won't help you to write the protecting code.

But there is hope for improvement. A proposal for a ["Optional Chaining for JavaScript"](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/) feature is still in stage 1, but quite active. Maybe the TypeScript team could start [an implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16) in the TypeScript compiler when the proposal will reach the stage 3?